# Maven Support to web Application

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web Application ( its a .war file to be specific) to be deployed in run time.
The requirement is provide a Maven support.

My questions
1. What maven support means here?
2. Also how to achieve this in current web Application project

Thanks,
Faraz

P.S. I am totally new to Maven

Comment: First search and learn what is maven and how it is useful in webapplication.If you face any problem in that then stackoverflow will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is project management tool, Maven provides developers ways to manage following:

- Builds
- Documentation
- Reporting
- Dependencies
- Releases

It can do wonders in your project. You have to do a lot of reading in order to understand the features provided my maven. [Maven's official site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) is the key for u.